# Angular $http post with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

What am I missing here? I'm trying to pass 2 fields(CustomerID and CompanyName) from my view into my controller. When I put a break point on my controller's action, both custID and Company name are null. I'm sure whatever I'm missing is easy but I'm just not getting into Angular. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="new.CustomerID" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="new.CompanyName" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.AddCustomer = function () {
    debugger;
    var urlPost = "/Home/SaveCustomer/";

    console.log($scope.new);
    alert(urlPost);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlPost,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },

        data: { custID: $scope.new.CustomerID, CompanyName: $scope.new.CompanyName }

    }).success(function() {
        alert('Update Successfully!');
    });

}
```

**C#**

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveCustomer(string custID, string CompanyName)
{

}
```

**EDIT**

A few weeks after this was posted and an answer was accepted, I found an easier way to accomplish this. Here is a code sample:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="CustomerID" ng-model="newCustomer.CustomerID" class="form-control" style="width: 130px" required/>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Name" ng-model="newCustomer.CustomerName" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" required />
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="newCustomer.CustomerEmail" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" required />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.newCustomer = { 
    CustomerID: '',
    CustomerName: '',
    CustomerEmail: ''
};
$scope.addCustomer = function () {
    $http.post("/Home/GetCustomer",
        {
            customerID: $scope.newCustomer.CustomerID,
            customerName: $scope.newCustomer.CustomerName,
            customerEmail: $scope.newCustomer.CustomerEmail
        }).error(function (responseData) {
            alert(responseData);
        })
    .success(function () {
        alert('Updated Successfully');
});
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetCustomer(int customerID, string customerName, string customerEmail)
{

    //do something with values
}
```

Comment: $scope.new = {
     CustomerID: '',
     CompanyName: '',
 }

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DUmAZp?p=preview

Comment: Can you please check the plunker and check console when click on add button

Comment: Hmmm..I just checked the console and it appears to be working as expected on plunker...I wonder what I could possible have wrong.

Comment: make your method httppost and action

Comment: Can you please show me you complete controller and html view on plunker or here. might be there is issue with scope

Comment: @MohanSingh -- I updated my question to show more code.

Comment: did your method has [HttpPost] annotatation and make it return JsonResult

Comment: Why is your naming messy and poor? Its rather hard to follow code that has 0 standards applied to it.

Comment: make $scope.new = {}; not any property setted inside it

Comment: This could all have been solved if you just posted JSON and had an object in your Api Controller instead of two parameters.

Comment: @Phill It's not a real application...I just wanted to play around with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean your problem is because the binding that web api uses there is base on querystring, so please update your code, I do an example:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Users/Save/{custID}/{CompanyName}")]
        public string Save(string custID, string CompanyName)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}",custID, CompanyName);
        }
    }
```

And the html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Demo</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="AddCustomer()" />
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.new = {
            CustomerID: "CustId1",
            CompanyName: "Company 1"
        }

        $scope.AddCustomer = function () {
            var urlPost = "/Users/Save/" + $scope.new.CustomerID + "/" + $scope.new.CompanyName
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlPost,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }

            }).success(function () {
                alert('Update Successfully!');
            });

        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

And if I test:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: This solution is just nasty.

Answer (score 0):

make these changes  :

```
//either define parent object scope only
$scope.new  = {}  

//or if you want to define child object too . May be to show some default value . 
$scope.new = {
 CustomerID: '', //empty or may be some default value
 CompanyName: ''
}
```